# Redux mapStateToProps not connecting correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to use Redux in my registration page so I created a user reducer:

```
const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TYPE_FIRSTNAME':
            console.log('typed first name ' + action.text);
            return { ...state, firstName: action.text };
        case 'TYPE_LASTNAME':
            return { ...state, lastName: action.text };
        case 'TYPE_EMAIL':
            return { ...state, email: action.text };
        case 'TYPE_PASSWORD':
            return { ...state, password: action.text };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

it is created like this:

```
    const AppReducer = combineReducers({
        nav,
        user
    });
export default AppReducer;
```

the **nav reducer** is for the navigation (used with react-navigation and it works fine). After that I created a container:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        firstName: state.firstName,
        lastName: state.lastName,
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    typeFirstName: (text) => {console.log('typed firstname');
    dispatch({type: 'TYPE_FIRSTNAME', text})},
    typeLastName: (text) => dispatch({type: 'TYPE_LASTNAME', text}),
    registerUser: () => {
        //register("mamad");
        console.log('called register user : ');        
        dispatch({type: 'MAINSCREEN'})
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps)(RegisterScene)
```

But it is never called, why?

Comment: You're saying that if you put a debugger on the `return {` line in `mapStateToProps` that it never gets hit?

Comment: What never gets called? If you're calling one of the action creators like `typeFirstName`, please show us that code

Comment: can you add your code to codesandbox.io

Comment: @TomFenech no, but when i trigger an action or print a props in the register  it doesn't have any effect, it just nothing happen at all her is all my code in the https://codesandbox.io/s/lr2xql2moq concerned folders are: containers, reducers and scenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I found is the `mapStateToProps`. I think it should be

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        firstName: state.user.firstName,
        lastName: state.user.lastName,
    }
};
```

It would be helpful if you put the error log here.

Answer (score 2):

When you combine reducers the state gets put into the specified state branch.

In your case you need `state.user`.

so your mapStateToProps function should look like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        firstName: state.user.firstName,
        lastName: state.user.lastName,
    }
};
```